# How to change Route respond To A specific Path?

Tags: uploads, redirect, media, cdn

To increase site loading time and decrease the pressure on my website I have decided to host files(js,css,images) in other hosting, like google storage or amazon aws, problem is that I already published a lot of posts that includes images other files in the html, like:

```
<img src="site.example/wp-content/uploads/images/image.png">
```

i can't go all over the posts to change the src attribute, so I want to change my route code so every time a wp-content or wp-includes files is requested, it will redirect it to the host where my media files are, something like:

```
    if(str_contains($path, 'wp-content') || str_contains($path, 'wp-includes')){
      redirect("host.example".$path);
    }
```

Comment: "i can't go all over the posts to change the src attribute" - yes, you can e.g. [wp cli search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/). Are you using a plugin to move images to Google or S3? I'd guess that plugin would do this for you too.

Comment: However if you did want to route this from your server I'd suggest doing it in .htaccess or the Apache or NGINX configuration, so it's handled outside WordPress entirely.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but how can I do it in apache?